# В чём ошибка запроса sql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Сделал базу данных на Access, сейчас установил sql server,SQL Server Management Studio. С помощью запросов создал сами таблицы, начинаю заполнение ,но не работает. К примеру запрос создания таблицы spr_Client `CREATE TABLE spr_Client(ID int,FullName char(75),PhoneNumber char(50),TypeOfJewerly char(50), Information char(100), PRIMARY KEY(ID));`. Начинаю заполнение `INSERT INTO spr_Client VALUES (1 ,"Artyom Staff","+37529868464","Ring","Ring from gold");`. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Строковые литералы записываются в одинарных кавычках.

Comment: Извините,можете пожалуйста подсказать где ошибка ```SELECT spr_Client.FullName AS Клиенты, Avg(spr_Order.Price) AS [Стоимость заказа]
FROM spr_Client INNER JOIN spr_Order ON spr_Client.ID=spr_Order.ID_buyer
GROUP BY spr_Client.FullName
HAVING Sum(spr_Order.Price)>1000;``` . Пишет что, Недопустимое имя столбца "ID_buyer".

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Либо отредактируйте этот, либо задайте новый отдельный.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку понял. Запись нужно записывать в одинарных кавычках.